# How to find and delete folders that are 15 days older using cron jobs in Truenas Scale?

Tags: linux, cron, truenas, find, rm

I have security camera in my home it upload recorded videos to my Home NAS every one hour time intervals which is powered by Truenas Scale Operating System now all the footage are stored in my NAS I allotted 500Gigs only do my surveillance backups.

So I want to delete the footage that are older than like maybe 15 days one days of my surveillance backups contains 24 folder each folder contains one hour videos so I want to delete 15 days of surveillance using cron and I don't know how to use cron.

I searched lots of forums but couldn't set it properly.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a shell script `clean.sh` that read

```
#!/bin/sh
find /viddata/daily -mtime +15 -delete
```

What that does is, start in the `/viddata/daily` folder, and in that folder and everything above, delete anything that's more than 15 days old. That shell script ended up in the folder `/home/me` - be very sure you know where that file is, yours will likely end up somewhere else. You'll need to tag it as executable also, with `chmod 755 /home/me/clean.sh`. I then ran `crontab -e`. That starts an editor that shows you the current `crontab` for your user. You'll probably get a wall 'o text that describes how to cron. The line that I put in at the bottom of that file reads

```
0 1 * * * /home/me/clean.sh
```

which says: At 0100 every day, run the script `/home/me/clean.sh`.

Because I'm old-school, started off before DOS even was a thing, I tend to do things on the command line. But there are of course GUI equivalents for all of this, which is why I tried to explain what I was doing. Your GUI will have slightly different options than any of mine do, so describing what I'd do in a GUI would take far longer.